# Give bounty and then earn more than 200 rep per day?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, bounties

Suggestion: If you have earned 200 rep one day and give away 50 in a bounty, you should be then able to earn those 50 rep points "back" that day. No?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not a good idea - it would have many side effects:

- Bounties are *supposed* to "hurt" - you invest something in order to get some engagement. The possibility to earn those points back would mitigate that.
- For high rep users, this would mean that they could start a bounty every day just using their surplus rep that they "make" beyond the 200 cap. This would be terribly unfair to other users.
- The reputation cap is designed as a means to stop people from spending too much time on the network. The possibility to circumvent it this way would undermine that (IMO very sensible) mechanism.

Comment: I think I agree after all.